# setting due dates+java+mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

I am trying to set a reminder form, I have MySql database table "chk_remindr" with column name as follows;

client_ID, name, bank_to_deposit, date_posted, amount, status.

I was able to retrieve those data and display in a jtable using

```
jTable_incomingChk.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

The problem is the jtable column status should display the number of days before the current due..

I realize I have to go through each row of my result set, get the date_posted column value, compare to current date, get the difference, and finally set jtable column "Status" #of days left before the due date.

I tried searching this site to look for same case but I can't find a code that will fit in my problem.

Please see the image included.. the last column status should display the number of days remaining before the due date.

Thanks in advance and looking for great responses..

can't post images as of the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this just by editing my MySql statement as follows;

```
String sql = "select client_id as 'Client ID', name as 'Name', bnk_to_dep as 'Bank to Deposit', date_posted as 'Date Posted', amnt as 'Amount', concat('days left',' ', datediff(date_posted, now()))as status from chk_remindr";
```

and then I use the same code below..

```
conn = ConnectDB.ConDB();
        if(conn==null){
            conn = ConnectDB.ConDB();
            System.out.print("connection close... openning ");
        }
        try{

            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();`enter code here`

            jTable_incomingChk.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```